# Exchage web service

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am using the Exhange Web Service Java plugin in netbeans at Java 7,

code

```
ExchangeService service = new
            ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials
            ("domain\\user","pass");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.autodiscoverUrl("email");
```

I am facing this error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/ExchangeCredentials : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: TestMail.ews.TestJavaMail.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I tried to change the settings projects-> properties -> source tab -> source/binary combobox to JDK 5. Still it giving me error

1. How to fix this error?
2. I am using the ews for first time, to read the email from ms exchange web service,  Could any one suggest me some examples/ tutorials to finish my task?

Thank you, I am happy to provide some more information if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just following the instructions from this forum

https://superuser.com/questions/335454/how-can-i-make-jdk-7-the-default-jdk-in-netbeans

1. find the program files->netbeans->etc->netbeans.conf, open with text file
2. change the path to JDK 1.7

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the Java Runtime you are using is not as Same as the JDK which was used to compile jar library where `ExchangeService` is available. Most probably it is 1.5 and you have 1.4 or lower. Please check your VM Version by issuing a `java -version` in command line.

Comment: close version 51.0 is actually a Java 7 compiled class. @vijay must be running with JDK 1.6 or below.

Comment: Ok, I am bit confused, let me provide the details I am using in my project Java Platform - JDK 1.6, Source/Binary format - JDK 6, Java Version "1.7.0".

Comment: should the java runtime environment and JDK should be in the same version?